# use wordpress thickbox with dynamic content in admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used wordpress row action for my custom post type which has goal to show some post meta and some other data about that post in a thickbox.
I'm searching for a way to do it dynamically for each post. any solution to handle this ?
this is the current row action link :

```
<a href="#TB_inline?width=600&height=550&inlineId=my-content-id&_post_id=' . $post->ID . '" class="thickbox">edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a thickbox require some steps :

***Step 1***

You need to add thickbox to your WordPress post. You can do this by adding the add_thickbox function to the ‘init’ function of your theme. In particular, add the code below to your theme functions.php file.

```
add_action('init', 'init_theme_method');
 
function init_theme_method() {
   add_thickbox();
}
```

***Step 2***

Now we can just add the button right in our post and link it to thickbox by specifying class="thickbox". Click on the HTML tab in your post editor and paste the HTML code below into your post.

```
<div style="text-align:center;padding:20px 0;"> 
<input alt="#TB_inline?height=300&amp;width=400&amp;inlineId=examplePopup1" title="add a caption to title attribute / or leave blank" class="thickbox" type="button" value="Show Thickbox Example Pop-up 1" />  
</div>
```

***Step 3***

Finally, we specify the content that goes into our pop-up window by creating a div with id="examplePopup1".

```
<div id="examplePopup1" style="display:none">
<h2>Example Pop-up Window 1</h2>
<div style="float:left;padding:10px;">
<img src="http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/bio1.jpg"  width="150" height = "168"/>
</div>
I was born at DAZ Studio. They created me with utmost care and that is why I am the hottie that you see today. My interests include posing, trying out cute outfits, and more posing.
 
<select name=""><option>test</option></select>
 
<strong>Just click outside the pop-up to close it.</strong>
</div>
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I guess you've been misunderstood. i don't have problem with using it. what i have problem with is to show post summery in the thickbox. so i need to pass some data or whatever in my thickbox. here is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an element inside the popup with an ID, then you can put any content into it (and you can change it any time):

```
<div id="examplePopup1" style="display: none;">
  <div id="placeOfDynamicContent">
  </div>
</div>
```

Load some content dynamically:

```
$('#placeOfDynamicContent').load('https://example.net')
```